# How to add eclipse milo to android project

Tags: java, android, opc-ua, opc, milo

I am trying to get an opc ua client running on an android device. I tried jitpack method
https://jitpack.io/#eclipse/milo/v0.6.8
it compiles but gives error when i run the app.
i downloaded the jar file using Maven
https://mavenlibs.com/jar/file/org.eclipse.milo/sdk-client
and that seemed to work but when i implement the code bellow I am getting an error with the .stack. part. When I look up the stack jar file from Maven
https://mavenlibs.com/jar/file/org.eclipse.milo/opc-ua-stack i get an xml file. I'm stuck on what the next thing is to do.

```
OpcUaClientConfig config = new OpcUaClientConfig() {
            @Override
            public org.eclipse.milo.opcua.stack.core.types.builtin.LocalizedText getApplicationName() {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public String getApplicationUri() {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public String getProductUri() {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public Supplier<String> getSessionName() {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public String[] getSessionLocaleIds() {
                return new String[0];
            }

            @Override
            public org.eclipse.milo.opcua.stack.core.types.builtin.unsigned.UInteger getSessionTimeout() {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public org.eclipse.milo.opcua.stack.core.types.builtin.unsigned.UInteger getMaxResponseMessageSize() {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public org.eclipse.milo.opcua.stack.core.types.builtin.unsigned.UInteger getMaxPendingPublishRequests() {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public IdentityProvider getIdentityProvider() {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public org.eclipse.milo.opcua.stack.core.types.builtin.unsigned.UInteger getKeepAliveFailuresAllowed() {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public org.eclipse.milo.opcua.stack.core.types.builtin.unsigned.UInteger getKeepAliveInterval() {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public org.eclipse.milo.opcua.stack.core.types.builtin.unsigned.UInteger getKeepAliveTimeout() {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public double getSubscriptionWatchdogMultiplier() {
                return 0;
            }
        };
```